# RestSharp Deserialization with JSON Array

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I have a JSON response that I'm trying to deserialize with [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/), and it looks like this:

```
{"devices":[{"device":{"id":7,"deviceid":"abc123","name":"Name"}},
            {"device":{"id":1,"deviceid":"def456","name":"Name"}}],
 "total":2,
 "start":0,
 "count":2}
```

Based off of some suggestions I've found, I've tried to setup my POCO like this:

```
public class DevicesList
{
    public List<DeviceContainer> Devices;
}

public class DeviceContainer
{
    public Device Device;
}

public class Device
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then my execution looks like this:

```
// execute the request
var response = client.Execute<DevicesList>(request);
```

However, `response.Data` is NULL, and I've tried other variations with no luck.

So, what class structure and mapping should be used for this situation? I've also tried this without the extra `DeviceContainer` class.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: May be you should add total, start and count properties to deviceslist class.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

RestSharp *only* operates on properties, it does not deserialize to fields, so make sure to convert your `Devices` and `Device` fields to properties.

Also, double check the `Content-Type` of the response, if the responses is something non-default, RestSharp may not uses the JsonDeserializer at all. See my answer on [RestSharp client returns all properties as null when deserializing JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087508/restsharp-client-returns-all-properties-as-null-when-deserializing-json-response/11087824#11087824)

Comment: That was it. Stupid mistake forgetting the `{ get; set; }`. Once I added that, it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

I had a slightly different issue when my deserialization POCO contained an array..

Changing it from `Devices[]` to `List<Devices>` resolved the issue and it deserialized correctly.

Comment: thank you, just got hit with this and your fix solved it

Comment: `IEnumerable<>` and `IList<>` don't work either. You need `List<>`

Answer (score 5):

Something that I ran into is, it does not work if your using interfaces like: IEnumerable or IList, it has to be a concrete type.

This will not work, where as it does for some other json serializers like json.net.

```
public class DevicesList
{
    public IEnumerable<DeviceContainer> Devices { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceContainer
{
   ...
}
```

it would have to be something like this:

```
public class DevicesList
{
    public List<DeviceContainer> Devices { get; set; }
}

public class DeviceContainer
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: This helps if you are using a newer version of RESTSharp (e.g. not using JSON.NET) for your JsonDeserializer

Answer (score 2):

RestShartp doesn't support DataAnnotation/DataMember, rename your properties with no maj:

- Devices -> devices
- Device -> device

AND don't forget the `{get; set;}` ;).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was entirely different, I naively thought `JsonDeserializer` supports `JsonProperty` attribute, but thats not true. So when trying to deserialize into

```
public class AvailableUserDatasApi
{
    [JsonProperty("available-user-data")]
    public List<AvailableUserDataApi> AvailableUserDatas { get; set; }
}
```

it failed.. But changing `AvailableUserDatas` to `AvailableUserData` was enough for things to start working.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net Core you can use native attribute (since Newtonsoft is deprecated):

```
public class AvailableUserDatasApi
{
    [JsonPropertyName("available-user-data")]
    public List<AvailableUserDataApi> AvailableUserDatas { get; set; }
}
```

Then it is possible to use any property name you want.