# Deserialize nested JSON Response with RestSharp Client

Tags: c#, json, poco, restsharp

I'd like to consume a REST Api and deserialize the nested JSON Response. For that purpose I tried to create some POCO classes which represent the JSON Response [1].
The response looks like this:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "OK",
  "types": 
  [
    {
      "name": "A5EF3-ASR",
      "title": "ITIL Foundation Plus Cloud Introduction",
      "classroomDeliveryMethod": "Self-paced Virtual Class",
      "descriptions": {
        "EN": {
          "description": "some Text null",
          "overview": null,
          "abstract": "Some other text",
          "prerequisits": null,
          "objective": null,
          "topic": null
        }
      },
      "lastModified": "2014-10-08T08:37:43Z",
      "created": "2014-04-28T11:23:12Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "A4DT3-ASR",
      "title": "ITIL Foundation eLearning Course + Exam",
      "classroomDeliveryMethod": "Self-paced Virtual Class",
      "descriptions": {
        "EN": {
          "description": "some Text"
          (...)
```

So I created the following POCO classes:

```
public class Course
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public List<CourseTypeContainer> Type { get; set; }
}

/* each Course has n CourseTypes */
public class CourseType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<CourseTypeDescriptionContainer> Descriptions { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
public class CourseTypeContainer
{
    public CourseType CourseType { get; set; }
}


/* each CourseType has n CourseTypeDescriptions */
public class CourseTypeDescription
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Overview { get; set; }
    public string Abstract { get; set; }
    public string Prerequisits { get; set; }
    public string Objective { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
}
public class CourseTypeDescriptionContainer
{
    public CourseTypeDescription CourseTypeDescription { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the API Code:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.someurl.com");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "password");

var request = new RestRequest();
request.Resource = "api/v1.0/types";
request.Method = Method.GET;
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

var response = client.Execute<Course>(request);
```

**EDIT 1**: I found a Typo, the `Type` property in AvnetCourse should be named `Types`:

```
public List<AvnetCourseTypeContainer> Type { get; set; }    // wrong
public List<AvnetCourseTypeContainer> Types { get; set; }   // correct
```

Now the return values look like:

```
response.Data.success = true                    // CORRECT
repsonse.Data.Message = "OK"                    // CORRECT
response.Data.Types = (Count: 1234);            // CORRECT
response.Data.Types[0].AvnetCourseType = null;  // NOT CORRECT
```

**EDIT 2**: I implemented the `Course.Types` Property using a `List<CourseType>` instead of a `List<CourseTypeContainer>`, as proposed by ***Jaanus***. The same goes for the `CourseTypeDescriptionContainer`:

```
public List<CourseTypeContainer> Type { get; set; }                     // OLD
public List<CourseTypeDescriptionContainer> Descriptions { get; set; }  // OLD
public List<CourseType> Type { get; set; }                              // NEW
public List<CourseTypeDescription> Descriptions { get; set; }           // NEW
```

Now the `response.Data.Types` finally are properly filled. However, the response.Data.Types.Descriptions are still not properly filled, since there is an additional language layer (e.g. "EN"). How can I solve this, without creating a PACO for each language?

**EDIT 3**: I had to add an additional CourseTypeDescriptionDetails class, where I would store the descriptive Data. In my CourseTypeDescription I added a property of the Type List for each language. Code Snippet:

```
public class AvnetCourseType
{
    public List<CourseTypeDescription> Descriptions { get; set; }
    // other properties
}
public class CourseTypeDescription
{
    public List<CourseTypeDescriptionDetails> EN { get; set; } // English
    public List<CourseTypeDescriptionDetails> NL { get; set; } // Dutch
}
public class CourseTypeDescriptionDetails
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Overview { get; set; }
    public string Abstract { get; set; }
    public string Prerequisits { get; set; }
    public string Objective { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
}
```

It works now, but I need to add another property to CourseTypeDescription for each language.

*OLD: The return values are*

```
response.Data.success = true            // CORRECT
repsonse.Data.Message = "OK"            // CORRECT
response.Data.Type = null;              // WHY?
```

*So why does my response.Type equal null? What am I doing wrong?*

Thank you

Resources:
[1] [RestSharp Deserialization with JSON Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156738/restsharp-deserialization-with-json-array)

Comment: Next time you need POCO classes based on some JSON sample try http://json2csharp.com. Sooo much easier :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this as POCO:

```
public class Course
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public List<CourseTypeContainer> Types { get; set; }
}
```

Now you have list of `CourseTypeContainer`.
And `CourseTypeContainer` is

```
public class CourseTypeContainer
{
    public CourseType CourseType { get; set; }
}
```

So when you are trying to get `response.Data.Types[0].AvnetCourseType` , then you need to have field `AvnetCourseType` inside `CourseTypeContainer`

Or I think what you want is actually  this public `List<CourseType> Types { get; set; }`, you don't need a container there.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured out the typo by myself as well :) I updated my question. It would list me now all Types, but those are all empty (null). What's wrong with my Code?

Comment: Can you check how many elements there are in response.Data.Types, then we know if atleast he gets something.

Comment: Yes it does get something. There are >2k response.Data.Types elements, but all of them are null..

Comment: Remove the container , just use list of CourseType.

Comment: Wow it really works when I use List<CourseType> Types!! :D Thank you so much!!
Can you explain me, in which case I'd need a container?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64853/discussion-between-ronin-and-jaanus).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps someone else, I tried everything here and it still didn't work on the current version of RestSharp (106.6.2). RestSharp was completely ignoring the RootElement property as far as I could tell, even though it was at the top level. My workaround was to manually tell it to pull the nested JSON and then convert that. I used JSON.Net to accomplish this.

```
var response = restClient.Execute<T>(restRequest);
response.Content = JObject.Parse(response.Content)[restRequest.RootElement].ToString();
return new JsonDeserializer().Deserialize<T>(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used http://json2csharp.com/ to create C# classes from JSON.
Then, renamed RootObject to the ClassName of the model file I'm creating
All the data in the nested json was accessible after RestSharp Deserializitaion similar to responseBody.data.Subject.Alias
where data, Subject and Alias are nested nodes inside the response JSON received.