# Parse JSON array to Object array

Tags: c#, json, restsharp, jsonparser

I know it's probably very trivial question but I can't seem to find an answer online..

Imagine I have a below JSON

`{"userId" : "myUser","sites" : ["site1", "site2"] }`

I would like to parse it to C# object `User` but `RestSharp` parser is failing to parse array correctly.
I tried implementing `sites` as below:

`public string[] sites = new string[5];`

`public List<string> sites;`

but nothing seems to work.

For deserialization I use

`JsonDeserializer deserial = new JsonDeserializer();`

`User newUser = new User();`

`newUser = deserial.Deserialize<user>(response);` --> response is a
`IRestResponse` object.

The code is correctly parsing the simple strings like `userId` but it's struggling with arrays...

What I am doing wrong? Is `RestSharp` not the right tool to do that?

What in case the is an object array in Json like

`{"userImgs" : {"small": "https://myImage.co.uk/small", "large" : "https://myImage.co.uk/large"}}`

Could I just have an object with an object as property an would the parser handle that if I implemented my class as below?

`Class User{`

`string userId;`

`UserImages userImg = new UserImages();`

Thanks

Comment: I think you are basically on the right track, and it's most likely a mismatch of the property name (sites) and what's actually in the JSON. Can you inspect the "IRestResponse" and see what the actual json is and include it?

Comment: @DanielJamesBryars - I basically copy-pasted my attributes from Json using Postman. And I also checked the names to be sure they are the same and they are... I'm sure of it

Comment: I hope this will help you: [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16157322/8978576)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using newtonsoft.

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    class User
    {
        public string userId { get; set; }
        public List<string> sites { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string response = "{\"userId\" : \"myUser\",\"sites\" : [\"site1\", \"site2\"] }";
        User obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(response);
    }
```

Comment: yeah, That's fine but I started using RestSharp and I bet there is a way to achieve this without adding new libraries.